# difference of continuous function and uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

unifomrly continuous function 
$$f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
if f is satisfying 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{ }f(n+x)=0, x\in\left [0,1  \right ]$$
show that if   f   is continuous function
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{ }f(x)\neq0$$

sol) I should not prove by definition of continuous function

How do i get proof of my problem?

I really some your help. thank you for my words

Comment: What if $f(x)\equiv 0$?

Comment: what your question mean? I should show that prove not limit f(x)=0.

Comment: What do you want actually? What is your conditions and want conclusions do you want to make? The function $f \equiv 0$ is a function that satisfies your assumption but not the conclusion. Can you edit your question to make it clear what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want an example of a continuous function $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(n+x) = 0$ for all $x$ but
$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \ne 0$?

Hint: consider a graph with thin triangles just to the right of the integers.

[image]